# Find lowest level in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to find the lowest level in a hierarchy that looks like the following:

```
ID ParentID 
1    NULL
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     3
9     3
10    9
```

I would expect to get the following back:

```
4,5,6,7,8,10
```

So essentially I would get the level that is not a parentID of anything else in the list. I am thinking a recursive CTE to do this but I have no clue how to figure this out.

I do have a recursive CTE to travel up and down this tree, but I don't know how to say these are the lowest levels

Comment: Wouldn't you expect ID 10 only?

Comment: No, I need all of the final levels, so the levels I have indicated have no more levels underneath them. For example level ten looks like this: 1->3->9->10 but level eight looks like 1->3->8 but 8 has nothing below it so that would appear as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No reason for any type of recursive CTE.

```
SELECT ID
FROM myTable
EXCEPT
SELECT ParentID
FROM myTable
```

Comment: This is great, does the distinct matter in this?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Good eye.  Edited answer.